# monclient(hunting): handle_auth_bad_method server allowed_method

Tags: ceph, cephfs

I am new to Ceph Storage but ready to learn.
I had been having this problem  since four days now. Just cant solve it

I had followed the steps in : https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/man/8/ceph-authtool/

The issue is I cant authenticated against the ceph cluster

```
root@node3 ceph]# ceph auth import -i ceph.admin.keyring
2022-05-10T14:34:37.998-0700 7f0637fff700 -1 monclient(hunting): handle_auth_bad_method server allowed_methods [2] but i only support [2,1]
2022-05-10T14:34:37.998-0700 7f0636ffd700 -1 monclient(hunting): handle_auth_bad_method server allowed_methods [2] but i only support [2,1]
2022-05-10T14:34:40.998-0700 7f0636ffd700 -1 monclient(hunting): handle_auth_bad_method server allowed_methods [2] but i only support [2,1]
2022-05-10T14:34:40.998-0700 7f0637fff700 -1 monclient(hunting): handle_auth_bad_method server allowed_methods [2] but i only support [2,1]
2022-05-10T14:34:43.998-0700 7f0637fff700 -1 monclient(hunting): handle_auth_bad_method server allowed_methods [2] but i only support [2,1]
2022-05-10T14:34:43.998-0700 7f06377fe700 -1 monclient(hunting): handle_auth_bad_method server allowed_methods [2] but i only support [2,1]
2022-05-10T14:34:46.998-0700 7f0637fff700 -1 monclient(hunting): handle_auth_bad_method server allowed_methods [2] but i only support [2,1]
2022-05-10T14:34:46.998-0700 7f06377fe700 -1 monclient(hunting): handle_auth_bad_method server allowed_methods [2] but i only support [2,1]
```

My directory

```
[root@node3 ceph]# ls -ls
total 40
0 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 May  5 00:15 admin.secret
0 drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    6 May  4 00:36 cephadm
4 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  144 May 10 14:33 ceph.admin.keyring
4 -rw-------. 1 ceph ceph  131 Aug 23  2021 ceph.client.crash.keyring
4 -rw-r--r--. 1 ceph ceph  958 May 10 12:39 ceph.conf
4 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  460 May  3 12:21 ceph.conf.ak
4 -rw-rw-r--. 1 ceph ceph 1302 Aug 23  2021 ceph-dashboard.crt
4 -rw-------. 1 ceph ceph 1704 Aug 23  2021 ceph-dashboard.key
4 -rw-------. 1 root root   41 May  5 13:30 ceph.key
4 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  145 May 10 14:27 keyring
4 -rw-------. 1 root root   56 May  2 11:31 keyring.mds.3
4 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root   92 Aug  5  2021 rbdmap
[root@node3 ceph]#
```

Really do need help on this

Comment: Which ceph version is this? How did you set it up (exact steps)? In the latest releases there is a keyring created for you if you deploy with `cephadm`.  Please update your question with all required information.

Answer (score 0):

i had exactly the same error

```
     # microceph.ceph  -n client.vasya  -s

handle_auth_bad_method server allowed_methods [2] but i only support [2,1]
```

the issue was that i wrongly named the keyring file,
that is :

```
wrong file name => ceph.client.vasya.keyring.conf
```

i renamed the file:

```
correct file name => ceph.client.vasya.keyring
```

the problem solved.

to make sure ceph finds keyring file  you can specify it  on command line

```
# microceph.ceph  -n client.vasya   --keyring=/var/snap/microceph/current/conf/ceph.client.vasya.keyring -s
```